# emacs auto indentation

Tags: emacs, latex

I have Auctex and auto indentation set in my `~/.emacs` but it doesn't work correctly for `\end{enumerate}`.

If I had the following, (below is what would happen if I hit tab on the `\end{enumerate}`

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item
    text
  \item
    text
  \end{enumerate}
```

So when I hit tab to auto align `\end{enumerate}` it aligns with `\item`.

This doesn't happen for other begin and enter commands so it is isolated to enumerate only.

How can I fix this?